# How to build a RouteValueDictionary when a route has multiple values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am creating a reusable method that inspects my model and automatically builds URLs (via `ActionLink`) for paging.  One of the properties on my model is a `string[]` (for a multi-select pick list) which is entirely valid.  An example of the URL would be: `https://example.com?user=Justin&user=John&user=Sally`.

However, as the name of the type implies, `RouteValueDictionary` implements `IDictionary` so it can't accept the same key more than once.

```
var modelType = model.GetType();
var routeProperties = modelType.GetProperties().Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(PagingRouteProperty)));

if (routeProperties != null && routeProperties.Count() > 0) {
    foreach (var routeProperty in routeProperties) {
        if (routeProperty.PropertyType == typeof(String)) {
            routeDictionary.Add(routeProperty.Name, routeProperty.GetValue(model, null));
        }

        if (routeProperty.PropertyType == typeof(Boolean?)) {
            var value = (Boolean?)routeProperty.GetValue(model, null);
            routeDictionary.Add(routeProperty.Name, value.ToString());
        }

        //The problem occurs here!
        if (routeProperty.PropertyType == typeof(string[])) {
            var value = (string[])routeProperty.GetValue(model);
            foreach (var v in value) {
                routeDictionary.Add(routeProperty.Name, v);
            }
        }
    }

//Eventually used here
var firstPageRouteDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(routeDictionary);
firstPageRouteDictionary.Add("page", 1);
firstPageListItem.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink("«", action, controller, firstPageRouteDictionary, null).ToHtmlString();
```

What can I use to build the routes when a key is needed more than once?

Comment: What is the type of `routeDictionary`? Is it regular `RouteValueDictionary`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that.  You are correct!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to specify the property name along with the indexer as the `Key`:

```
if (routeProperty.PropertyType == typeof(string[])) {
    var value = (string[])routeProperty.GetValue(model);

    for (var i = 0; i < value.Length; i++) {
        var k = String.Format("{0}[{1}]", routeProperty.Name, i);
        routeDictionary.Add(k, value[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Just try to imagine how the link would look and it should make sense

```
new RouteValueDictionary { { "name[0]", "Justin" }, { "name[1]", "John" }, { "name[2]", "Sally" } }
```

which will generate the following query string

Encoded

```
?name%5B0%5D=Justin&name%5B1%5D=John&name%5B3%5D=Sally
```

Decoded

```
?name[0]=Justin&name[1]=John&name[3]=Sally
```